# How do I add header file for a C++ console app in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++

I'm studying C++ from the book *"Programming Principles"* 2nd edition by Bjarne Stroustrup. In the book the author encourages students to use a header file from "http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h" to build a project in Visual Studio 2017.

However, the instructions on how to use it are unclear.

My questions are:

- How do I save the header from the web site (what program)?
- What extension?
- How do I link it to my project?
- How do I enable it up once its linked?

I'm using Windows 7 and VS 2017.

Comment: "What extension?": It's extension is already `.h`. "How do I link it to my project?": You don't link header files, you include them.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I save the header from the web site (what program)?

1. Load the file in your browser.
2. Press Ctrl+S
3. Navigate to the folder where you want to save it

Alternative:

1. Right click on the link
2. Click on Save Link As... (or something similar depending on your browser's wording)
3. Navigate to the folder where you want to save the file.

> How do I link it to my project?

In the above steps, you should save the file inside your VS project folder.

> How do I enable it up once its linked?

Once you save the file, you use a `#include` to use it in a `.cpp` file. Your book should explain more about what `#include` is for and how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

> -How do I save the header from the web site (what program)?

It is just a text file. Download it using your web browser. Alternatively, copy the contents to any other text file.

> -What extension?

The file extension doesn't matter. In general, C++ uses `.h`, `.hpp`, `hxx`, `.H`, `.hh` and other file extensions for header files. It is usually a matter of style. I prefer `.hpp`. Make sure to be consistent.

> -How do I link it to my project?

It is a header file, not a library. You don't need to link anything. The linker shouldn't cause any problems.

> -How do I enable it up once its linked?

You don't enable or disable a header file. That doesn't make sense.

Just put the text file into your project directory, and `#include` it.

Warning: This file is outdated and it [won't compile](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ZFFLTD) with modern versions of MSVC.